# IActionContextAccessor Is Null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, middleware, actioncontext

I am setting up a custom Middleware for my .NET Core Application to log exception errors and have the following in the Startup.cs to register my  contexts:

```
   services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
   services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

And in my Configure I have added the following to use a custom middleware:

```
   app.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware>();
```

My custom Middleware class is the following:

```
 public class CustomMiddleware
 {
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public CustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(context);
            await this.next.Invoke(context);
            this.EndInvoke(context);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //Capture the exception.
            string hostName = Environment.MachineName;
            string url = StringFunctions.getCurrentUrl(context);
            string userName = string.Empty;
            string controllerName = string.Empty;
            string actionName = string.Empty;

            //THIS IS NULL BELOW.
            IActionContextAccessor contextAccessor = context.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IActionContextAccessor)) as IActionContextAccessor;
            RouteData routeData = contextAccessor.ActionContext.RouteData;

            if (context.User != null)
            {
                userName = context.User.Identity.Name;
            }

            if (routeData != null && routeData.Values != null)
            {
                controllerName = routeData.Values["controller"].ToString();
                actionName = routeData.Values["action"].ToString();
            }

            EventLogging.LogApplicationError(hostName, controllerName, actionName, url, userName, ex);
        }
    }

    private void BeginInvoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        //custom work here
    }

    private void EndInvoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Do custom work after controller execution
    }
}
```

It seems that the 'contextAccessor' that I am trying to get the ActionContext.RouteData values from is Null.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Have you made sure that **IActionContextAccessor** is registered in Startup.cs?

Comment: I have             services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>(); in my ConfigureServices function in my Startup.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IActionContextAccessor.ActionContext` is null outside the scope of mvc middleware.

If all you care about in your exception handler is `MVC` actions, you create an action filter instead of middleware to capture and log exceptions.

```
public class CustomExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        //Capture the exception.
        string hostName = Environment.MachineName;
        string url = StringFunctions.getCurrentUrl(context.HttpContext);
        string userName = string.Empty;
        string controllerName = string.Empty;
        string actionName = string.Empty;

        if (context.HttpContext.User != null)
        {
            userName = context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        }

        controllerName = context.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        actionName = context.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

        EventLogging.LogApplicationError(hostName, controllerName, actionName, url, userName, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: GetCurrentUrl takes HttpContext not ExceptionContext, so guessing I will have to inject the IHttpAccessorContext in for that?

Comment: You can access it via `context.HttpContext`. I updated the code

Comment: Thank you. I have registered it in my services using             services.AddMvc(config => config.Filters.Add(new CustomExceptionFilter())).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2); and it working fine in all controllers.