# Controller and Action from Global Error Handler

Tags: asp.net-core, error-handling, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm migrating an web api from .Net to .NetCore.

We had a custom ExceptionFilterAttribute to handle errors in a centralized way. Something like this:

```
public class HandleCustomErrorAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext filterContext)
   {
     // Error handling routine
   }
}
```

With some search, I managed to create something similar on .Net Core

```
public static class ExceptionMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static void ConfigureExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler(appError =>
            {
                appError.Run(async context =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

                    var contextFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    if (contextFeature != null)
                    {
                        //logger.LogError($"Something went wrong: {contextFeature.Error}");

                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(new ErrorDetails()
                        {
                            StatusCode = context.Response.StatusCode,
                            Message = "Internal Server Error."
                        }.ToString());
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

I need to find a way to access these 3 info that where avaiable in .Net in .Net Core version:

```
filterContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
filterContext.ActionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: You need  to add an `ExceptionFilterAttribute`. Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58119145/3667938

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a complete solution with registering `ExceptionFilter` and get request path, you could try like

1. ExceptinoFilter

   ```
   public class ExceptinoFilter : IExceptionFilter
   {
           public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
           {
           string controllerName = context.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
           string actionName = context.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
           var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
           var requestUrl = request.Scheme + "://" + request.Host + request.Path;
           }
   }
   ```
2. Register

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddControllersWithViews(options => {
           options.Filters.Add(new ExceptinoFilter());
       });
   }
   ```