# .net 7 Api ActionContext only available in AuthenticationHandler when having at least 2 schema's registered

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-core

I have a weird situation in my asp.net core api project. I am tryin to access the `ActionContext` via the `IActionContextAccessor` is an `AuthenticationHandler`. Now I found out, that when I have only 1 `AuthenticationScheme` registered, the returned `ActionContext` is `null`, but once I add a second `AuthenticationScheme`, the `ActionContext` is properly returned.

The code below is a minimized reproduction scenario. I have a program.cs that sets up the authentication schemes. When I call a random api route in the project, and have a breakpoint in the `HandleAuthenticateAsync` method, I see the `ActionContext` is filled. However, once I comment out the line that registers the `Schema2` authenticationhandler, the `ActionContext` becomes null. When hitting the same breakpoint.

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

my program.cs:

```cs
using AuthHandlerTest;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter());
});
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddScheme<Schema1Options, Schema1>("schema1", null);
    .AddScheme<Schema2Options, Schema2>("schema2", null);
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder("schema1").RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
});

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

my Schema1.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;

namespace AuthHandlerTest;

public class Schema1Options : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
{
}

public class Schema1 : AuthenticationHandler<Schema1Options>
{
    private readonly IActionContextAccessor _actionContextAccessor;

    public Schema1(IOptionsMonitor<Schema1Options> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock, IActionContextAccessor actionContextAccessor) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
        _actionContextAccessor = actionContextAccessor;
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        //this variable is null when only having 1 scheme registered
        var actionContext = _actionContextAccessor.ActionContext;

        var claims = new[]
        {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "aa"),
            };

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "schema1");
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), "schema1");
        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
    }
}
```

schema2.cs is identical to schema1.cs, only the 1's are replaced with 2's.

I also see that the stacktrace is significantly different between the working and non-working scenario.

Working:
[image: Stacktrace of working situation]

Non working:
[image: Stacktrace of non-working situation]

Now I understand why these different stacks are causing the `ActionContext` to be available or not, because in the working situation the `ResourceInvoker` is present in the callstack, and this component makes sure the `IActionContextAccessor` gets the `ActionContext` property filled. The million dollar question is, what is causing the difference in callstack

Update:
I've added a full reproduction scenario [here](https://github.com/PaulVrugt/actioncontextexample)

Comment: `app.UseAuthentication(); app.UseRouting();` is the wrong order for middleware. You want `app.UseRouting(); app.UseAuthentication(); app.UseAuthorization(); app.UseEndpoints(...);` It's `.UseRouting` that resolves the endpoint and attaches that information to the `HttpContext`, which `UseAuthorization / UseAuthentication` then use to enforce the requested auth policy. Otherwise you can only enforce the fallback policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58118280/iactioncontextaccessor-is-null) and

> IActionContextAccessor.ActionContext is null outside the scope of mvc
> middleware

Part of source codes of [Authentication middleware](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/AuthenticationMiddleware.cs)

```
var defaultAuthenticate = await Schemes.GetDefaultAuthenticateSchemeAsync();
        if (defaultAuthenticate != null)
        {
            var result = await context.AuthenticateAsync(defaultAuthenticate.Name);
            if (result?.Principal != null)
            {
                context.User = result.Principal;
            }
            if (result?.Succeeded ?? false)
            {
                var authFeatures = new AuthenticationFeatures(result);
                context.Features.Set<IHttpAuthenticationFeature>(authFeatures);
                context.Features.Set<IAuthenticateResultFeature>(authFeatures);
            }
        }

        await _next(context);
```

If the default scheme is not null ,`context.AuthenticateAsync(defaultAuthenticate.Name);` would be executed in Authentication middleware (as shown by the stacktrace),which means the handler would be called out of the scope of mvc middleware

The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/7.0/default-authentication-scheme#new-behavior) related with this issue

> Starting in ASP.NET Core 7.0, if (and only if) a single scheme is
> registered in an application, that scheme is treated as the default.
> In the following code, the CookieDefaults.AuthenticationScheme is
> treated as the default scheme.
>
> However, in the next code snippet, no default is set because multiple
> schemes are registered.

To disable it :

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.SuppressAutoDefaultScheme", true);
```

It works onmyside now:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I see I posted the wrong image in the "wrong stack", I'll update it

Comment: I've also added a link to a reproduction scenario

Comment: Yesterday I tried in .net 6 and failed to fully repo, builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddScheme<Schema1Options, Schema1>("schema1", null) would also work,but if I specifc the default scheme  builder.Services.AddAuthentication("schema1")
    .AddScheme<Schema1Options, Schema1>("schema1", null) I would partially repo

Comment: I tried with your scenario today and reproduced the issue ,seems when you regist only one scheme,it would consider it as the default scheme.

Comment: well, maybe, but does that explain why the ResourceInvoker is left out? Because I fail to see why having a default schema stops the need for having the ResourceInvoker involved

Comment: Please check what I've updated ,when the default scheme is not null,your handler would be called in Authentication middleware out of the scope of mvc middleware

Comment: Your first trace indicates you've hit the endpoint and got into the filter ,but the second indicates the handler was called in Authentication middleware before you hit the endpoint  that 's why the ResourceInvoker is left out

Comment: Yeah I've checked and you seem correct. But even explicitly setting the `DefaultAuthenticationScheme` and `DefaultScheme` to null in the `AuthenticationOptions` object doesn't seem to help. This seems very unwanted behavior, because we lose the entire mvc middleware scope

Comment: I found the related document and updated my answer

Comment: AppContext.SetSwitch("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.SuppressAutoDefaultScheme", true); would solve this issue

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, setting that flag seems like a temporary workaround. Apparently MS thinks this new behavior should be correct. I'm not sure if they accounted for this side effect

Comment: Here's a issue related on github:https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44661 ,"We have no intention of removing this switch. Indeed, if this scenario (single authn scheme but no default) is common enough we can consider elevating the property on AuthenticationOptions that wraps the switch to be public in .NET 8."

Answer (score 0):

You should check the order of your middlewares, you are registering Authentication before Routing.
See the official documentation about the middleware registering order => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#middleware-order

Comment: you are absolutely correct, however, changing the order or the `UseRouting` and `UseAuthentication` doesn't fix the issue

Comment: Did you try specifying the default scheme to use when having multiple Scheme ? Because when you have only one Scheme it is set by default as the default AUTHENTICATION scheme but when you provide multiple scheme you need to specify to the Authentication Middleware which one is the default one and it is completely different from the Authorization :)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/7.0/default-authentication-scheme